# How to implement level auto upgrade UI in react-native apps

Tags: react-native

I want to implement a UI similar to level upgrade map in candy crush in react-native[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pjGb.jpg)

Comment: This question is very vague. Please be precise.

Comment: Actually i want to implement a UI in my existing app similar to Candy Crush level Map